Geographic transformation won't auto-populate during projection
When I try to convert a layer of point data, in WGS 84 format, to NAD 83 15N format in order to match my basemap layers, the Geographic Transformation does not auto-populate.

Do I need to manually input a geographic transformation (and if so where can I find that information?) or am I doing something wrong?

Disclosure: I work for Esri.
Look at the properties of the input layer in a map and see if the WKID of the spatial reference/coordinate system is 4326. I suspect the WKID will be zero or blank because there's something in the GCS that doesn't match Esri's definition. If so, reassign the coordinate system of the input layer using the Esri version.
Another possibility could be is the data doesn't fall within the NAD 1983 extent. Check the extent (plus coordinate system if not a geographic one) of the input data.

Thanks so much for this suggestion. The WKID was actually filled, but I had the thought to check what coordinate system the data was originally collected in. Sure enough, the data was actually recorded in NAD 83 15N, which is why the project tool wasn't working. When I imported the dataset as a text file and converted to a layer in GIS, I must have overlooked the coordinate system tab and just left it as the default (WGS 84).
To fix the issue, I simply used the "define projection" tool and chose NAD 83 15N and the layer showed up on my map with the other NAD 83 15N layers.
